# IOS Swift application and Google Analytics questions

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I want to create a small chat application of IOS swift and I am still a beginner in it but I have some experience and knowledge with android studio. Also, I am not very familiar with Google analytics, thus I apologize if the following questions seem ridiculous or easy:

1)  Can I use Google Analytics to track a user's behaviour on IOS Swift?

2)  My specific concern if I can track how much each user will use the keyboard or voice recording message?

3)  Do you recommend or suggest any resource to tutor IOS Swift or Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to implementing Google analytics into an iOS app, there documentation is normally pretty good.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3